# Retrieve an object (PHP&ANGULARJS)

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to retrieve an object sent from an Angular function to a PHP program.
Here is my view:

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content padding="true">
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider text-center">
    Authentification
  </div>
  <div class="item item-text-wrap text-center">
    <form>
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" ng-model="user.username">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="mot de passe" ng-model="user.password">
        </label>


      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="item item-divider text-center">
    <a  href="" class="button button-positive button-small" ng-click="logIn(user)">
      <i class="ionicons ion-android-share"></i>
      Identifiez moi, vite !
    </a>
    <a  href="" class="button button-energized button-small">
      <i class="ionicons ion-android-mail"></i>
      Mot de passe perdu !
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="button button-large button-full button-positive">
  je n'ai pas de compte
</button>
```

Here is controller :

```
'use strict';

app
.controller('homepageIndex',function ($scope) {
})
.controller('homepageLogin',function ($scope , userProvider) {
  $scope.user={};

  $scope.logIn = function (user) {
    console.log($scope.logIn);
    console.log($scope.user);
    userProvider.logIn(user);
  }


 })
 ;
```

Here is my userProvider.js

```
'use strict';

app.factory('userProvider', function ($rootScope , $http) {

  function logIn(user) {
    var url='http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/service/rest.php';

    $http.post(url,user)
      .success(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
        console.log(url);

      });

  }

  return {
    logIn: logIn
  }
});
```

In my file `rest.php` I want to retrieve this object user which contains username and password:

```
$username =$_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
```

This method doesn't work i want to know how to retrieve username and password in my rest.php 
Thank u for ur help.

Comment: Could you show how the `user` variable looks like?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: u can see now, here is my view and controller et my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mohit Tanwani

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

You can put this at the start of your PHP script.  $request will then be an stdClass object with the data as properties.

```
$username = $request->username;
$password = $request->password;
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to work with it as assoc array, use:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
```

and access data like:

```
$username = $request['username'];
$password = $request['password'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following code.

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/service/rest.php',
 data: { username: 'username', password:  'password' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){
   //Success
}, function(){

});
```

Comment: dosent work because i have data in user who contain username & password

Comment: @CHARAFISaad : still you are facing issue ? provide me more details what exactly you're facing